# Copy rows with JOpenDocument

Tags: java, jopendocument

I am trying to copy a row several times using JOpenDocument v1.3 and I am failing miserably.

Here is my code snippet:

```
   private void copyRow(Sheet sheet, int templateRow, int target){
      sheet.ensureRowCount(target);
      sheet.duplicateRows(templateRow, 1, 1);
      sheet.insertDuplicatedRows(templateRow, target);
   }
```

No row gets changed with the code above and no error is displayed.

I know I could copy each cell separately but I think if there is a way to do it all at once it should be more efficient.

Thanks in advance.